# d3 table dynamic updation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a table in d3 as below from data as below. Now I want to update only 2 cells for example  data[0][0] = 10 and data[1][1] = 10;

```
 var data = [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ],
        [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ],
        [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ] ];
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");
var tbody = table.append("tbody");
var rows = tbody.select("tr").data(data);
rows.enter().append("tr");
var cells = rows.selectAll("td").data(function(d) {
    return d;
}).enter().append("td").text(function(d) {
    return d;
});
data[0][0] = 10;
data[1][1] = 10;
tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data).selectAll("td").data(function(row) {
    return row;
}).text(function(d) {
    return d;
});
console.log(data);
```

Now I would like to update the td. How shall i do that. Even updating with new data the cells are not getting updated.
console output will give updated data.

Comment: Rebind the data. Without a [MCVE], I'm afraid that this is the best answer you'll get.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, it **is** updating, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/4s4ex9r1/ . So, what's exactly your problem? Also, in `rows`, you have a `select` where it should be `selectAll`.

Comment: Yes strange it dosent work for me but after your comment it started working strange.